# How to use two adapter(LS and Rest adapter) to a model(Foo - ModelName), but route based access/use the adapter in ember.js application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I use the LS adapter to Foo model in first page, I defined/mentioned the DS.LSAdapter to that Foo model and get the model data from database to the local storage. after I can access/manage the model data using by local storage adapter in the first page. It is working fine here.

Next I will navigate to second page and this page model is defined/mentioned the Rest Adapter for Foo same model. Ember does not make REST API call here, because the problem is first LS adapter initiated in the first page and this second page is not initiate the REST adapter for that Foo model. How do we initiate the rest the adapter to Foo model in second page without page refresh?

Please you give the solution to fix it. Thank you so much.

**Model**

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({     
id: DS.attr('id'),     
name: DS.attr('string')    
});
```

**Mention the Local Storage Adapter in first page**

**Controller**

```
App.FirstPageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

**Route**

```
App.FirstPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 

    model: function() {  

        App.FooAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({ namespace: 'ls-emberjs' });

        return this.store.find('foo');       

    }   

});
```

**Hbs**

```
<ul>
{{#each model}} 
    <li>fooID: {{id}} - Name: {{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Mention the Rest Adapter in second page**

**Controller**

```
App.SecondPageController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

**Route**

```
App.SecondPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  

    model: function() {  

        App.FooAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({});

        return this.store.find('foo');       

    }   

});
```

**Hbs**

```
<ul>
{{#each model}} 
    <li>fooID: {{id}} - Name: {{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want a clear and good answer, make a nice question with a bit more code :)

Comment: Added more codes above. Please give your solution/feedback to us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, For what i deduce from the issue is that the adapter deduction based on "name" works only at load, so i think you will have to try something like this to dynamically change adapter. It's the first time i see this requirement and the ember doc is also limited so it's a trial and i didn't tested it :

```
App.FirstPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 

model: function() {  

       var adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({});
       this.set("store.adapter",adapter);
       return this.store.find('foo');       

    }   
});

App.SecondPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 

model: function() {  

       var adapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({ namespace: 'ls-emberjs' });
       this.set("store.adapter",adapter);
       return this.store.find('foo');       
    }   

});
```

If anyone from the ember team has a better solution ...

P.s. Ive re pushed up the post as it's now possible to understand the author ... :)

Comment: I tested/checked your above solution with my application. It is not working here and I am getting an error "while loading route: TypeError: undefined is not a function". Please ember team will give better solution to us.. Thanks.

Comment: on which line do you get the error ...and which of my calls is not "defined" ?

Comment: This line code is getting that undefined error in my application. "this.store.set("adapter",adapter);"

Comment: i tried with a direct set as adapter is a property of store as state in the doc : http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#property_adapter